# integrate admob into android twa app generated using bubblewrap

Tags: android, admob, progressive-web-apps, twa, bubblewrap

Following the below google [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/adaptive-banner-android-studio#3) tutorial, i am trying to add admob code into the android project source/app generated by bubblewrap.

on step 3, as per instruction, it is adding framelayout to show bannerad to mainactivity.xml. However i am not finding this xml file in the project. Which file/place is the right to add this banner ad within the app generated by bubblewrap?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix Android native elements with Trusted Web Activity.

A [Trusted Web Activity (TWA)](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity) is just a special state of the Chrome for Android browser similar to [Custom Tabs](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs). The TWA takes up the full screen.

See: [Taking Chrome Full Screen with Trusted Web Activities (Google I/O ’19)](https://youtu.be/6lHBw3F4cWs?t=360). As mentioned in the video, [you can't draw the example native toolbar at the bottom of the screen with a TWA](https://youtu.be/6lHBw3F4cWs?t=402), and AdMob for Android uses native mobile views.

So native mobile views like AdMob's banner view isn't possible.

Comment: Are there any alternatives for AdMob? Is there any way to monetize TWA app by ads?